# Local module import tree possibility?

Tags: import, pyscript

In my local package, there is a tree of modules, like this:

```py
# source/main.py
from source import worker
def run():
    return worker.func()
```

```py
# source/worker.py
def func():
    return 'hello'
```

I want to demonstrate this package with PyScript (before my package needs to be installed), but do not want to rewrite the whole package for the sake of PyScript. This "index.htm" calls the *main.run()*. It is OK until the main wants to import the *worker* module so that it can call its *func()*.

```xml
<head>
    ..
    <py-env> 
        paths:
        - source/main.py
        - source/worker.py
    </py-env>
</head>
<body>
    <py-script>
import main
main.run()
    </py-script>
</body>
```

The "import worker" would work, but as I stated above, it is "**from source** import worker" and cannot be changed just to make it work in PyScript.

Could I define somehow that the root for the local module imports is above "source", and imports like "import source.module.py" should work?

Comment: Are you serving these files using a web server or an application that provides web server features?

Comment: Files are provided by web server.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do
**from source import worker** 
because source is not a module, it is a folder. Pyscript is not same as python. The whole context is different. There is no need for it also. You can have it all together working and reachable if you declare nodes **py-env and py-script** like below.
index.html in application root folder:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="pyscript.js"></script>       
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js" onerror=scriptLoadFailure('pyscr ipt.js')></script>      -->
        <py-env> 
paths:
    ./source/worker.py
    ./source/main.py
        </py-env>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <py-script src="./source/worker.py"></py-script>
        <py-script src="./source/main.py"></py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The modules in py-env are declared with exactly 4 spaces indentation (no tab char) and starting from application root folder ( **./** ) folowed by subfolder and module. In body section both modules are declared as **src attribute of py-script nodes.** This way they are like unioned and operational without import one or other nor from one import something. You can just call the function from wherever you need to.
The modules are both in the source subfolder (though I prefer puting main in the app root along with index.html). There is just one change in main.py where I put the call  of run() function for it was excluded from html.
Modules in ./source/ subfolder are

```py
#
# source/main.py
def run():
    return func()
run()

#
#
# source/worker.py
def func():
    return 'hello'
```

Open it in browser and you'll see hello (tested with Chrome & Edge) meaning that run() command from main.py has called func() function from worker.py without importing anything.
And if you realy need to keep those imports all I can suggest is to do a replace of those imports to end up like below. It can be done with any editor and it will work both with python and pyscript.

```py
try:
    from source import worker
except:
    pass
```

Regards...

Comment: This answer does not help, unfortunately. The package (e.g. containing main.py and worker.py) are not what we can fiddle with. They import modules from source, and actually from many other subdirectories. I want Pyscript or Pyodide make handle the tree. It has already been clear that Pyscript is not the same as Python, and this is the issue here. I am after a solution where Pyscript or Pyodide can simulate it. Let me emphasize: whatever is under "source", it cannot change at all.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have nothing else to offer. I'm affraid that there is no solution for pyscript (in this stage) to "handle the tree". Maybe someone else could ...

Answer (score 0):

Since the current PyScript does not do such, I created a patched version and proposed the PyScript project to pull it into a future version. See the ticket with my comment and the attached zip containing the solution:
[Add Local Package Loading to Py-Env #519](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/519#issuecomment-1208881190)